# Update Query not working in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to update two fields in SqLite database but its not working  there is no exception showed in LogCat but I am not being able to get any value for these 2 specific fields while getting the values.

Here is the code i am trying.

```
try{
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("iTimeDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor cur =db.rawQuery("UPDATE Activities SET Details = '"+ detail_edit.getText().toString() +"' AND Time = '"+Ctime+"' WHERE ID = '" +ID+"'", null);
    Log.d("Time", ID);
    cur.close();
    db.close();
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
     e.printStackTrace();
     Log.v("SSS", e.toString());
     }
```

I have also tried to UPDATE these fields separately but same problem.

Tried this but same result no update

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE Activities SET Details = '" + detail_edit.getText().toString() + "', Time = '" + Ctime + "' WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'", null);
```

**SOLUTION**
as aswered by laalto

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE Activities SET Details = ?, Time = ? WHERE ID = " + ID,
    new String[] { 
        detail_edit.getText().toString(),
        Ctime
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but does not execute it. Use `execSQL()` instead to both compile and run the SQL.

Additionally you have an SQL syntax problem that does not cause a syntax error:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar=1 AND baz=2
```

is really

```
UPDATE foo SET bar=(1 AND baz=2)
```

where the result of the expression in parens is put to the first column and the second column is not modified.

To update more than one column, separate them with `,`:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar=1,baz=2
```

---

> Tried this but same result no update
>
> ```
> db.execSQL("UPDATE Activities SET Details = '" + detail_edit.getText().toString() + "', Time = '" + Ctime + "' WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'", null);
> ```

Also check that the `WHERE` condition actually matches. You're  matching `ID` as a string literal, I believe you want it without the `'` quotes to match as integer instead.

While there, your code has an SQL injection vulnerability: directly putting string from user input into SQL. Use `?` in SQL where you'd use a literal and pass in the params in `bindArgs`:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE Activities SET Details = ?, Time = ? WHERE ID = " + ID,
    new String[] { 
        detail_edit.getText().toString(),
        Ctime
    });
```

Comment: i have updated the code as you have suggested but same result ... check the update  in Question

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public void updateBattingFieldingData(int gameId, int batterTeamId,
        int fielderTeamId) {
    String string = " SELECT * FROM " + GAME_LIST_TABLE + " WHERE "
            + KEY_GAME_ID + " = " + gameId;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_BATTING_TEAM, batterTeamId);
    values.put(KEY_FIELDING_TEAM, fielderTeamId);
    db.update(GAME_LIST_TABLE, values, KEY_GAME_ID + " = " + gameId, null);

}
```